# If your question would be of interest to professional programmers, you should ask it on Programmers, not on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, faq-contents

In the ["don't ask" section](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) of our FAQ it says:

> If your question would be of interest to …
>
> - **Professional and enthusiast programmers**, ask on Stack Overflow.

Well, that's not right, if your question would be of interest to professional programmers, you are most likely in the right place. That part of the FAQ is not editable by mods, so we'll need a Stack Exchange employee's help to change it. Also, I can't think of a better phrasing, just that the current one sucks.

Thoughts?

Comment: "ask on SO" part is likely blindly copy-pasted from SO FAQ, which [currently says](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) "Stack Overflow is for **professional and enthusiast programmers**..."

Comment: @gnat I'm hoping it's copy pasted and not automatically generated (that's the "site description" the API returns for SO), if it's copy pasted it will be a lot easier to change.

Comment: well [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions) guys somehow managed to get it right in their FAQ: "for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity..." Hope it's doable for Programmers as well

Comment: I think that line is auto-generated because we have SO as a migration target. To change it's wording, we'd have to change the SO tag line, which is probably not going to happen. You'd probably have a better chance at getting it removed than changed.

Answer (score 6):

For the time being, I would just drop those two sentences.

1) As it stands, it's potentially redirecting questions that *should* be on P.SE over to SO.  (Say it with me: d'oh! Bart!)

2) Unlike [SO's don't ask FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) we're not suggesting any other site.  And perhaps we should, but that's another matter.

3) Our `don't ask` section would read just fine without those two lines.

4) That's not the place to draw out a differentiation between P.SE and SO, which is what would be required to properly redirect.

5) I have a quibble about the professional vs. enthusiast aspects, but this question isn't the place to hash that out either.  I'd say we're open to all programmers, not just professionals but I may be using too narrow a definition of professional in this case.

TL;DR

I would say to drop those two lines that you quoted.

Comment: Dropping the quote completely wouldn't be a bad idea, we already mention Stack Overflow in our off topic list at the start of the FAQ.